# ament_cmake_python job

Tags: ros, ros2, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that `ament_python` is for building packages using python's `setup.py` and (for now) users can not mix `ament_cmake` with `ament_python` in the same package.

The question is what does `ament_cmake_python` do? and an explanation with a use-case/example would make me happy.

Sorry, there is just some lack of information/use-cases out there about some of `ament` functions.

Originally asked as a comment here https://answers.ros.org/question/349571/what-is-ament_cmake-job/?answer=349871#post-id-349871

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350012/ament_cmake_python-job/) by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While documentation is sparse, you can usually get useful information from the function/macro documentations.
Did you try looking at the content of the ament_cmake_python package?
At a glance it contains only [2 macro definitions](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/tree/dcc2a7050b6fd8d2445724a268eb256e07a214cf/ament_cmake_python/cmake) which name and docblocs are pretty explicit.

- `ament_python_install_module` to install python modules
- `ament_python_install_package` to install python packages

> I know that [...] (for now) users can not mix ament_cmake with ament_python in the same package.

```
grep -rl "ament_python_install_package(" | sort -u | grep CMakeLists.txt | wc -l
41
```

It appears that 41 packages in the `[ros2.repos](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/blob/0a62b2cd2210b06be7570c00922cd2f3d6609e31/ros2.repos)` file do install python packages from `ament_cmake` packages. There may be restrictions or good reasons not to mix `ament_cmake` and python packages but it looks like in some cases it is doable and done.

**Edit:**

An example of package using it is [rqt_plot](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_plot/blob/e33182b68827897d5cd959fa75a0735f2ef32718/CMakeLists.txt#L7)

> Are the Python packages installed here are:

> - PyPi packages and whls only

- ros2 packages with setup.py (including the current one that the
  CMake is building)
- both of the above

My understanding from reading the docblock is that it installs the python package you point to and any sub-package in that same directory (sub-directories containing an `__init__.py`).
It does not require any `setup.py`, just the presence of an `__init__.py` file
So I expect it to install noting outside that directory, no other ROS 2 packages and no Pypi packages, only recursive subpackages

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aby](https://answers.ros.org/users/52503/aby/) on 2020-04-22**:
I looked at the Github page before but I was not able to read such CMake file at my current early stage.
These are questions to clarify the answer above.

1. Where to run this grep command? in which of the ros2 repos?
2. Are the Python packages installed here are:

   1. PyPi packages and whls only
   2. ros2 packages with setup.py (including the current one that the CMake is building)
   3. both of the above

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-04-23**:
I edited the answer above to add a link to the ros2.repos file and answer the follow-up question